# phpdockerio/php:8.2-fpm custom log

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

Im using  FROM phpdockerio/php:8.2-fpm

I add

```
access.format = "[%t] %m %r%Q%q %s %{mili}d %{kilo}Mkb %C%% %{HTTP_HOST}e%R"
access.log = /proc/self/fd/2
```

to php-ini // overrides php config

but still in docker compose out i see.

```
[27-Mar-2024 11:36:24] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
2024-03-27T11:36:24.181379275Z [27-Mar-2024 11:36:24] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024-03-27T11:36:24.181454215Z [27-Mar-2024 11:36:24] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
2024-03-27T11:37:21.041966846Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:37:20 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
2024-03-27T11:37:21.210769787Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:37:18 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
2024-03-27T11:37:21.791410589Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:37:21 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
2024-03-27T11:37:22.322265485Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:37:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
2024-03-27T11:37:23.135867990Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:37:22 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
2024-03-27T11:37:23.311216809Z 127.0.0.1 -  27/Mar/2024:11:36:48 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
```

possible to see request uri ?

I`m using Symfony 6.4 application

Comment: Where do you add these `access.*`?